# Css positioning without background image

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem in positioning a text at the top of the image. The image is not in background.It's just with image tag.

The thing is I can't change the html code. Is it possible to achieve what I want but without changing the html code.

```
<div class="home_box">
<img src="http://netdna.seospecialist.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/christmas-three.png" class="holding">
<h4>hot off the server</h4>
</div>
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EkzdE/11/

I have updated the fiddle. Now when you resize the window the image is moving but the text is staying there.Is there any way to make it **responsive**

Comment: you should not make major changes in your questions half way people have started to answer it. It is annoying and levels the answer quality down.

Comment: Sorry for that. Actually when I resized the browser suddenly the responsive thing came in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EkzdE/13/)**

CSS:

```
.home_box {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
img.holding {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:40px;
}
.home_box h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-family:'arial';
    font-size: 15px;
    left: 140px;
    line-height: 33px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
    height:40px;
    left:50%;
    top:0;
    margin-left:-100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my fiddle and this question too.

Comment: Actually in my code the image is shrinking while you resizing the browser.So when the image is getting shorter the text is not going with it.

Comment: I don't understand. On my fiddle, the image is always the same size. and the text is following as you asked.

Comment: Yes your answer is correct but I didn't take care of the responsive thing while posting this question.Sorry once again.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra if you still need the text on the top I updated my answer, it should be what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This is what I was looking for. Only thing that I want to do later on to resize the whole div(including image and text).Let me try with that one. Thanks once again.Accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

Write:

```
.home_box h4 {
    width: 200px;
    top:0;margin:0;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/EkzdE/3/)

Comment: Thanks Hiral. I have updated my fiddle and this question too.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra question is not clear. please elaborate

Comment: When you resize the browser then the image is moving from center to left but not the text.Please check my latest fiddle posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the `h4` element's top property to zero so it sits at the top of the div, right over the image.

```
.home_box h4 {
    ...
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    ...
```

}

[**Here is an updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/EkzdE/10/)

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my fiddle and this question too.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra My response is responsive, Right?

Answer (score 1):

You should make the positioning on both the image and the text `relative`.

This ensures that they both move according to the div as the window size changes.

Then, in order to put the text on top of the image, use a negative top margin.

```
.home_box {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}
img.holding {
    position:relative;
}
.home_box h4 {
    color: #000;
    font-family:'arial';
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    line-height: 33px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkzdE/11/)